# HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions, cant call

Tags: google-apps-script

I follow the instruction here but it not work for me.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

in Script Editor I was crate 2 file Code.gs and Index.html same as above link said. then I publish as web app. go to web app url and it show "hello world" -> it work for the Index.html but when back to Script Editor and chose View->log nothing here. Just "logging out" string show here. I guess that mean it fail to call server-side function. I still don't know how get it work.

Comment: Which code are you using? If you published a 'Hello World' HTML page and then subsequently changed the version, are you sure your using the latest version of the script you saved: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

Comment: @HDCerberus thank , i was miss that.

Comment: If that solved your issue, I'll leave it as an answer.

Comment: This question is very poor. That link has many instructions - which ones did you follow, exactly? As @HDCerberus asked, show your code! I'm happy you got an answer, but in its present state this question is of no value to the community and really needs to be improved.

Answer (score -1):

If you published a 'Hello World' HTML page and then subsequently changed the version, you'll need to ensure that you're using the latest version of your code: developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions